# Deploy RoR application to Heroku getting "a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

in the images above are all the errors I can find. I have updated yarn, webpacks, bundler, and ruby. Honestly don't have any idea why it is not working. I have deployed in the past without a problem. These are the errors below that are from the heroku terminal.

```
remote:        You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
remote:        Bug reports are welcome.
remote:        For details: https://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
remote:        
remote:        Aborted
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...


###### WARNING:
       There is a known bundler bug with your version of Ruby
       
       Your version of Ruby contains a problem with the built-in integration of bundler. If
       you encounter a bundler error you need to upgrade your Ruby version. We suggest you upgrade to:
       
       2.6.6
       
       For more information see:
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.1.4
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin bundle install -j4
       Fetching https://github.com/doabit/semantic-ui-sass.git
       The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.


Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       yarn install v1.22.4
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 32.34s.
       yarn install v1.22.4
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@3.7.2" has incorrect peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 6.25s.
       /tmp/build_1c2393a0/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/sassc-2.4.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:43: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000000
       ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-linux]
```

I have also deleted the gemlock file and re-bundled. I am also using the devise gem it does seem to stall when I try to send the code to heroku. I am also using the CLI and tried the github deploy. Both are not working.

Comment: That error says your Ruby version is 2.6.1 and it is recommending upgrading that to 2.6.6 to avoid this known bug.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I thought I did but I have to be doing something wrong. It won't let me update from 2.6.1. I brew installed the new version on my laptop but it's still saying the version on 2.6.1.

Comment: Sure but you have to set it and then if there is a file like `.ruby-version` in your app, or maybe being set in the `Gemfile`, you will have to update that too.  Are you using something like rvm or rbenv?  Make sure you also push to github and then deploy, otherwise the change won't get sent to Heroku.

Comment: I have tried both rvm and rbenv. My local machine will not update from 2.6.1 to anything else either 2.7.1 or 2.6.6 it say it is not supported or it will say it updated but when I do ruby -v it gives me ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin19] so I can't update my application. I really don't know what to do at this point

Comment: How are you setting it after you download it?  It won;t just update but if it is unsupported you may have to try 2.7.1.  If you set it in the gemfile to 2.6.6, what ahppens?

Comment: Thank you for your help. To find out the issue was with active storage and aws bucket storage

Comment: If you were able to resolve the issue, it might be useful if you answer your own question with guidance on how you solved the problem.

Comment: I am still working on the solution at the moment. I had to rollback before I added aws

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was not Ruby. It was the fact I was using AWS s3 bucket and active storage. When using active storage in a rails app you need a ruby build pack and an [active storage build](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku) pack. Then you need to set up the bucket on Heroku on AWS side and you need to use specific rules on setting up the buckets. Then you have to feed keys and bucket name into Heroku. [Here is the link for the s3 stuff.](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3)